# Check if column was grouped (QueryBuilder)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, query-builder

I have the following query:

```
$qb
   ->select('z')
   ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
       $qb->expr()->like('z.city', ':czRequest')
   ))
   ->groupBy('z.city')
   ->setParameter('czRequest', $cz . '%');
```

With `$cz = 'Ber'`I get an array like this:

```
array:3 [
 0 => array:4
  [ "id" => 12899 "country" => "DE" "city" => "Berlin" "code" => 14199 ]    
 1 => array:4
  [ "id" => 6483 "country" => "DE" "city" => "Berlingen" "code" => 54570 ]
 2 => array:4
 [ "id" => 8438 "country" => "DE" "city" => "Berlingerode" "code" => 37339 ]
]
```

Now 'Berlin' gives more than one (zip) 'code', in this example '14199' is obviously only the last one. 'Berlingen' on the other hand only has one code.

Is there any way to alter the query so that I have 'various' instead of '14199' but keep the others?
It does not have to be in the query itself, I think maybe a 'foreach' for the query (w/out the groupBy) and check for duplicate cities?

Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve your need with that:

```
$qb
  ->select('z, CASE WHEN (COUNT(z)) > 1 THEN \'various\' ELSE z.code END AS code2')
  ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
    $qb->expr()->like('z.city', ':czRequest')
  ))
  ->groupBy('z.city')
  ->setParameter('czRequest', $cz . '%');
```

You have to count your result (for a group by) and depending on the count, you can switch for a name or another.